# how can I model sculpture parts and exporting them for laser cut without distortion?

Tags: modeling, uv, export, sculpting

I am a blender beginner. I am making metal sculptures by welding laser cutted pieces. normally I am drawing several random shapes and exporting them as dxf/dwg files. I use those random shapes , deforming them by hand and welding them.

I decided to create more accurate pieces. I modeled a face then I Uv unwrapped . I exported that unwrap and cut it. However, as you might imagine unwrapping was different then the real shape. While eyes and nose are very top of the head become huge. It did not satisfy me because of size distortion. (I am adding picture of my trial with face unwrapping)

I am looking for a solution to produce more accurate pieces. for instance, I want to project curved 3d forms (like nose)  to 2d surface with minimum distortion. then I can bend those pieces with hand and weld it together. to sump up, I am waiting for any advice that help me to design metal pieces closer to the original blender design.

Thanks for your help :D

an example with random pieces:

[image: an example with random shapes]

laser cut of Uv unwrapping :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try the paper model addon? It is part of the standard addon catalogue and it should help you unwrap your model distortion-free. You can find documentation here: https://blender-addons.org/export-paper-model-addon/

Comment: thanks, I already tried that add-on . However it works only with geometric and basic forms. Although, it is  very helpful, l I am looking for a solutions with more curved and organic forms

Comment: I just got an idea: As you can only lasercut planar elements anyway, you could use a decimate modifier set to "planar" before exporting...

Comment: thank you again. I tried, while geometry simplified parts are still deforming and at some points it is deforming even more. But  I  guess there is no way to create 2D layout of 3D round object without tension/distortion.

Comment: The only thing you can do is limit the distortion to an amount you're comfortable with, but a perfect unwrapping is geometrically impossible, I am afraid.